# Choosing to display or not to display a menu item in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Is there a way i can choose to include or leave out a menu item in ExtJS?.

```
var actions = {
        newTask: new Ext.Action({
            //text_field_display: true,
            text: 'New Task',
            iconCls: 'icon-active',
            tooltip: 'New Task',
            handler: function(){
                taskHeader.ntTitle.focus();
            }
        }),
```

The text_field_display is just an example and not something you will find in the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the hidden property to hide any component that uses that action.